# Fixed font size in iOS 14 widget with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

For an iOS 14 widget I want to fix the font size in the widget, even when a user has its settings to bigger type in accessibility settings (larger type). I want this because the text is already very big (big digital clock widget), and if it is even bigger the text falls of the widget and therefore is not legible. I am using a custom font.

I tried to fix the font size with `.font(.custom("MyCustomFont", size: 17))`. But even then the type is rendered bigger depending on user settings. How can I permanently fix font size in a iOS 14 widget? Is there a workaround or another method to fix font size for the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.environment(\.sizeCategory, .large)` to enforce the size category. Here is an example:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("text1")
        Text("text2")
    }
    .environment(\.sizeCategory, .large)
}
```

The [default](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/sizecategory) category is `large` but [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/contentsizecategory) you can find more categories.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand correctly the default size, if the slider at accessibility settings is in the center, is large?

Comment: @Vincentin yes, exactly.