# Globally Fix Font Size for System Fonts in iOS 14+

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to use system fonts in my SwiftUI text, but these fonts automatically scale with the user's accessibility settings.

```
Text("abc").font(.system(size: 12))
```

Non-system fonts have this [fixedSize initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/custom(_:fixedsize:)) which allows it to not adjust to user settings, but there's no equivalent version for system fonts.

```swift
Text("abc").font(.custom("Arial", fixedSize: 12))
```

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291292/fixed-font-size-in-ios-14-widget-with-swiftui) on here proposes using the environment to fix the font size, but unfortunately this doesn't apply to sheets. (This might be a bug similar to the one with environment objects not being passed into sheets). So I have to add this line for every view that is presented modally, plus the root view of my app.

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ...
    }
    .environment(\.sizeCategory, .large)
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to globally fix the font sizes for my app, rather than setting the environment key for every possible view that could be presented modally?

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4 - if specify system font with explicit size it remains as-is, only dynamic-sizing fonts are scaled like Font.body, Font.title, etc.

Comment: ah my mistake, I was using system font styles like .body and .title, which is why they were scaling